# Is this user logs into the website - Must check up on whether it already exists

Tags: c#, global-asax

I've been working on, you can only log in to their profile one of time. There, I think that, for example, must not only be for example, userid = 1 twice at the same time.

It should be such that this option will only be assigned to a user and it is him / her who log in first at the single user ID which is assigned.

The file will be made by Global.asax.cs file.

Right now it's possible that only log in multiple simultaneous ID.

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        // check  sessions here
        string UserIdText = "Userid";

        if (ctx.Session[UserIdText] != null)
        {
            using (var DB = new ordklarEntitiesDatabase())
            {
                var sessionId = ctx.Session.SessionID;//unique sessionID
                var UserId = ctx.Session[UserIdText].ToString().ToInt();//Userid session
                var sessioncheck = DB.SessionId.FirstOrDefault(i => i.SessionIdValue == sessionId && i.Userid == UserId);
                if (sessioncheck == null)
                {
                    ctx.Session[UserIdText] = null;
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult("~/Account/login");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the user to be able to open website in only one browser tab? If user tries to open it in other browser or tab, user should not be allowed to open?

Comment: Yes or that you do not have the opportunity to be two at the same time in the user ID.

Comment: What issue you are facing with the current code